# How to add a 401 handler for angular2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-routing

My services are layout as follows

```
class BaseService {
  protected handleError() {
    // Logics for handling error
  }
}

@Injectable()
class PostService extends BaseService {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.http
      .get(url)
      .subscribe(cb)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Now I want to the BaseService to redirect the user to the login page on receiving 401, but this pollutes every derived service by having them also injected the Router which doesn't look quite right since the derived service doesn't need this provider. This version is listing as follows:

```
class BaseService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  protected handleError() {
    // Logics for handling error

    if (status_code === 401) {
      this.router.nagivate(['/login']);
    }
  }
}

@Injectable()
class PostService extends BaseService {
  // Polluted here↓
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    super(router);
  }

  getPosts() {
    this.http
      .get(url)
      .subscribe(cb)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

Then I tried to find a way to manually get the injected router provider:

```
class BaseService {
  private router: Router;

  costructor() {
    let injector = ReflectiveInjector.fromResolvedProviders([Router]);
    this.router = injector.get(Router);
  }
}
```

This doesn't work as I didn't provide all the tokens Router needs:

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'Router'(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'Router' is decorated with Injectable.

Given the context, my question is two-folds:

1. Given the context, how to correctly handle the 401 error in one place?
2. Is there any alternatives that I can use a service without injecting it via constructor?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried marking the `BaseService` class as `@Injectable()` ?

Comment: I use something like this, it might help you: https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/03/angular2-http-authentication-interceptor/